# Date in R - converting to custom layout from given format

Tags: r

I have a date value "11/7/2016 11:51" which is currently in "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" format. I want to convert this date to "2016-11-07 11:51:00" i.e "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" format using ***R language***.

I would like to have any suggestions/help. Thanks in advance.. !!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.POSIXct` from `base R`

```
as.POSIXct( "11/7/2016 11:51" , format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
#[1] "2016-11-07 11:51:00 IST"
```

If we want to change the timezone, there is `tz` argument

Answer (score 0):

Or `mdy_hm` from `lubridate`

```
lubridate::mdy_hm("11/7/2016 11:51")
[1] "2016-11-07 11:51:00 UTC"
```

`lubridate` will default to timezone UTC.

`as.POSIXct` will default to your (computer) timezone.